Run LLama 2 on GPU
I want to run LLama2 on a GPU since it takes forever to create answers with CPU. I have access to a nvidia a6000 through a jupyter notebook. I have installed everything and the responses are fine but it takes so long and isn't fast enough for my research purposes.
import torch
import transformers
from transformers import LlamaForCausalLM, LlamaTokenizer
import setGPU

model_dir = "llama/llama-2-7b-chat-hf"


model = LlamaForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_dir)
tokenizer = LlamaTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_dir)

pipeline = transformers.pipeline(
    "text-generation",
    model=model,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    torch_dtype=torch.float16,
)


sequences = pipeline(
    'I wanna hear some news. What is up today',
    do_sample=True,
    top_k=10,
    num_return_sequences=1,
    eos_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id,
    max_length=400,
)

for seq in sequences:
    print(f"{seq['generated_text']}")

This is my current code. When I try nvidia-smi in terminal, the GPU is always at 0% whereas the CPU RAM increases extremely, so it's 100% running on the CPU. How can I make it run on the GPU?
I have made this tutorial directly from meta: https://ai.meta.com/blog/5-steps-to-getting-started-with-llama-2/

You have imported setGPU, but not used it anywhere in your code, why not?

I found out how it worked. Set device="cuda" after the imports and device=0 in the pipeline.
